# Porting Silverlight app to Flex

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, apache-flex, porting

Perhaps a dumb question, but if you write a relative simple 2D game in `.NET` (e.g. for Silverlight) C# and you want to port it to `Flex` - just because you know C# and don't want to bother with other language, are there any means to facilitate this porting process?

Let's suppose that we are using **FRAME BASED development** (as Flash is, opposed to TimeLine in Silverlight) using the `CompositionTarget.Rendering event`.

I pose this question because I would like to try to create a fully functional app in .NET and then port it to `Flex`.

Comment: If you get this done; we'd love to interview you for The Flex Show on your experiences.  I think it'd be valuable to a lot of our listeners.  Drop us a line if you think you'd be interested: http://www.theflexshow.com/contact/contact.cfm .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no direct way to do this, unfortunately.  This is unfortunate, because Silverlight and Flex are so insanely similar to each other.  Pretty much every feature in either has an analog in the other... but the language (AS3 vs C#) and the UI declaration (MXML vs XAML) is different in both platforms.

You can consider using MVVM for the majority of your behavior logic along with some good unit tests.  Port the unit tests over to AS3 and get your MVVM code rocking using "Presentation Model" in Flex.  Then, convert the UI using brute force.

Some resources to get you moving forward:

- C# to AS converter: http://cs2as.codeplex.com/
- C# to AS3 converter: https://code.google.com/p/cstoas3/
- C# to Haxe converter: http://cs2hx.codeplex.com/
- Visual Studio plugin for Flex: http://www.ensemble.com/products/tofino.shtml
- A series (in development) about cross-training in SL & FLex: http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2010/10/24/cross-training-in-silverlight-vs-flex/
- An example using Presentation Model: http://riarockstars.com/2011/03/16/presentation-model-and-multiple-screens-part-1/

Good luck, and make sure to blog about what you've learned about doing this.  I am VERY interested to see someone do it.

Comment: +1 for all the converter links.  I'd also be very interested to see someone do this.

Comment: Good answer, however I wouldn't call Flex and Silverlight similar.  The only similarity that they have is that they try to accomplish the same thing, but the code behind it and how both function is so different that it's not comparable.

Comment: @J_A_X: I am sorry, but I disagree.  Silverlight and Flex are extremely similar.  The syntax is different, but the paradigms are all the same.  They maintain an extremely high level of feature parity and all of the abstractions they expose are much the same.

Comment: @Brian, I don't want to argue, but when it comes to development, they're hardly the same.  Try theming/skinning with XAML and come back to me.  Take a vector from Illustrator and try to implement it in Silverlight.  Try using CSS....

Comment: @J_A_X: I am well aware of how Silverlight works. I have been developing with it for about 3 years now.  Built some amazing apps with it. Skinning in XAML is different, sure, but most of the concepts are the same. No CSS in XAML but they have "Styles"... including implicit styles. Vector art from Illustrator in Silverlight? Expression Blend is your tool. It works just like Catalyst. Again, the mechanics are slightly different but all of the concepts are the same. I maintain that a Silverlight and Flex talent is easily transferrable because they are so similar. Also, not "same" but "similar".

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen anything for this. The languages/platforms feature nothing in common so any converter would basically be brute force. Unless someone has taken the time to create a converter (doubt it), you're going to have to do it manually.

Of course, that's just a presentation tier. You could conceivably build all the logic as services and have a .net engine underlying the Flex presentation like you would any flex or silverlight app that relied on a separate service tier.